# Call function in javascript gives error

Tags: javascript

i am reading about call function in js.
Now i have this code

```js
var o = {
  name: 'i am object',
  age: 22
}

function saymyName(arguentToFunc) {
  console.log('my name is ' + this.name + 'and thw argument  passed is ' + arguentToFunc);
}

saymyName.apply(o, 'hello there');
```

But it gives an error message saying `Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type`

In the book the definite guide it is written that the second argument is the value passed to the function. eg here it is `hello there`
So why the error?

Hey according to the book
.`apply needs this`
what does If a function is defined to accept an arbitrary number of arguments, mean? i mean arbritary??

Comment: Hey why am i downvoted?

Comment: @Yeah but i was confused!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) requires an array of parameter, you should use it as

```
saymyName.apply(o, ['hello there']);
```

or else you could use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
saymyName.call(o, 'hello there');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [*call*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) instead of [*apply*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), as *apply* needs the second parameter to be an Array–like object.

Use *apply* when an array of values needs to be sent as parameters to the called function (e.g. to pass all the arguments of the currently executing function using the *arguments* object).

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/g4s05uvx/1/)

```js
var o = {
  name: 'i am object',
  age: 22
};

function saymyName(arguentToFunc) {

  console.log('my name is ' + this.name + 'and thw argument  passed is ' + arguentToFunc);
}

saymyName.call(o, 'hello there');
```

Also, see [*bind*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for how to set a function's *this* to a fixed value, regardless of how it's called.

Comment: what does If a function is defined to accept an arbitrary number of arguments, mean? i mean arbritary??

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Do we really need to tell you [how to look up words in a dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arbitrary)?

Comment: @poke the dictionary contains many meanings  dude... which one will fit here... Mr. Cool guy??

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini—"*an arbitrary number*" means any number, though functions can accept from 0 to ??? arguments.

Comment: @RobG Thank you for improving answer :)