method decorator's originalMethod.apply un-defines parameters?
I have found similar questions, but most of them seem to focus on this and usually not purely typescript. However, I have a MINIMAL RUNNABLE EXAMPLE , that I just can't find an answer to.
I'm not understanding why the originalMethod.apply(this, args) seems to log undefined for it's parameters. Some suggest circular references, while other suggest using target, BUT, the code is so simple here, that there are no circular references I see and yes I did use target as well (RUNNABLE CODE), yet the result's the same. I have even avoided using arrow function
Does the originalMethod.apply not pass on the parameters? Why is the method body printing undefined for it's supplied parameters? Is this a typescript bug?:
function ValidateInputParams() {
    return function (target: any, key: any, descriptor: any) {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        console.log('original method descriptor: ', originalMethod);

        descriptor.value = function (request: any) {
            const inputBody = request.body;
            const inputParams = request.params;

            console.log(inputBody, inputParams)

            console.log('Inside the descriptor', request.body);
            return originalMethod.apply(this, request); // supplying target also not working
        }; 
    };
}


class MyClass {

    @ValidateInputParams()
    myWork(request: any) {
        console.log('REQUEST INSIDE MYCLASS',request)
        return;
    }
}


new MyClass().myWork({body: 'Test body method'})

This is the output:
[LOG]: "original method descriptor: ",  myWork(request) {
        console.log('REQUEST INSIDE MYCLASS', request);
        return;
    } 
[LOG]: "Test body method",  undefined 
[LOG]: "Inside the descriptor",  "Test body method" 
[LOG]: "REQUEST INSIDE MYCLASS",  undefined 


This really feels like a problem where you use apply incorrectly, and not anything at all to do with decorators. You either want call and the parameter, or apply and an array of parameters. I'm closing this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229667/call-function-in-javascript-gives-error, willing to reopen if you explain why it differs. Good luck!

@Jcalz, I did pass [request] which seems to work, so 'incorrectly using apply' does seem to be the case. But, I'm not understanding why it wasn't erroring out? For e.g. Math.min.apply(null, 3) seems to error out

"error out"? Do you mean why didn't TS warn you? Because you're using any which effectively turns off type checking.

@jcalz , no, not just the linting, there's no exception thrown, even in the runnable example, it's not thrown. Had it thrown an exception, I would see the mistake I made earlier. I literally fiddled for hours :-D

Hmm, that's a question about JavaScript (and possibly the specific JS engine you're using). apply() apparently accepts an "arraylike" argument. I don't know what counds as "arraylike" in every environment, but a number like 3 doesn't seem to be one, whereas an arbitrary object literal kind of does. This is an interesting question which is out of scope here and if you want an authoritative answer you should probably ask it separately in a new post (after searching for existing questions).
